# How To Compile Multiple Column Values Into One Under Corresponding Primary Key In Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset:

```
pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':['1','2','3'],'Genre':['Adventure|Children|Fantasy','Horror','Comedy|Drama']})

    ID  Genre
0   1   Adventure|Children|Fantasy
1   2   Horror
2   3   Comedy|Drama
```

I want it to look like this:

```
    ID  Genre
0   1   Adventure
1   1   Children
2   1   Fantasy
3   2   Horror
4   3   Comedy
5   3   Drama
```

How can I do it with Pandas?

Comment: `str.split` + `explode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `df.set_index` + `.explode()` on splitted `Genre`:

```
df.set_index('ID')['Genre'].str.split('|').explode().reset_index()
```

---

```
  ID      Genre
0  1  Adventure
1  1   Children
2  1    Fantasy
3  2     Horror
4  3     Comedy
5  3      Drama
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) the *words* and join them with the corresponding `ID`*s* :

```
out = df[["ID"]].join(df["Genre"].str.extractall(r"(?P<Genre>[^|]+)").droplevel(1))
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

  ID      Genre
0  1  Adventure
0  1   Children
0  1    Fantasy
1  2     Horror
2  3     Comedy
2  3      Drama
```